# How to use Process.Start within IoT Edge?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-iot-edge

I'm trying to start a process from a module within Azure IoT Edge, but I'm getting:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): No such file or directory
```

Code within my module:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
     {
         FileName = "dotnet --info",
         UseShellExecute = true,
         RedirectStandardOutput = false,
         RedirectStandardError = false,
         CreateNoWindow = true
     };

Process.Start(startInfo);
```

I guess that -as IoT Edge modules run from within docker containers- I don't have permissions to run Process.Start(), but I have no idea how I can gain this access for my module.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to start the process inside your container?  or on the host? If inside the container, have you installed dotnet core in it (or confirmed that it is installed)?

If so, and assuming this is a Windows container, can you try manually running the command from a command line in it by 'breaking into' the running container at a command prompt?

docker -H npipe:////./pipe/iotedge_moby_engine exec -it  cmd

That should give you a command prompt inside the container..  you can try your 'dotnet --info' there and see what happens

Comment: I'm running this on a raspberry pi 4, so it's using arm32v7. I understand now that the Process.Start() is executing fine, but it doesn't recognize processes outside the docker container.

For instance chromium-browser, which is installed on the pi, I can't just "run" it. That's probably a better example than dotnet --info, I just assumed that dotnet had to be available as my module.csproj runs on netcore3.1

Comment: Ah, sorry..  just assumed Windows...   yeah, I don't *think* you can start a process on the host from within a container, but don't know for sure...  

if you want to try your existing container with 'priviledged' access, you can add that into your HostConfig section of the container create options.

    "HostConfig": {
        "Privileged": true
}

Comment: Actually this is one of the features/advantages of containers: isolation. Giving a container access to the host process tree kinda breaks it. Still, it can be done by running a container with --pid=host (and depending on the permissions needed --privileged). Better to have all dependencies inside your container though. In case you really need your container to talk to a host process, consider using IPC mechanisms.

Comment: So in IoT Edge, that would translate into this in your container create options:

"HostConfig":{
    "Privileged":true,
    "PidMode":"host"
}

Comment: I've added "Privileged": true, "PidMode": "host" to HostConfig, but I still get the same exception unfortunately.

Comment: Installing chromium itself within the container doesn't seem to work, as it requires a desktop environment as well. The browser really needs to be visible on the machine.

Comment: http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2014/09/11/running-gui-apps-with-docker/ this does look promising, but I keep getting exception 'Unable to open X display'.

How can I do this properly within IoT Edge?

Comment: I'm very curious why are you trying to run a GUI inside the container itself, which I've not seen anyone else try..  but that's a separate question.   Per that article, are you mapping in the X11 socket to the container in your create options?

                "HostConfig": {
                    "Binds":["/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix"]
                }

Comment: I want to use Iot Edge to open a browser remotely, for narrowcasting purposes. That gives us monitoring and flexibility.

Yes that's exactly what I use. I've added this to EdgeAgent, EdgeHub and my own module, as I don't know exactly where to put it. I don't get to set the display variable properly, I try to set this variable now within my .arm32v7 dockerfile with ENV DISPLAY=:0.0

Comment: it should go in the Container Create Options for your module  (no need for edgeAgent and edgeHub).   You can also set environment variables in your deployment as well as part of your deployment...  are you deploying via the portal?  code?  cli?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Code to deploy. Does the same hold for Privileged and Pidmode, that it's only necessary in the custom module?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221226/discussion-between-noppey-and-steve-busby-msft).